# How do I fix this error with the Twitter authentification with Flutter and Firebase?

Tags: flutter, twitter, firebase-authentication, twitter-login

I keep getting this error while trying to set the Twitter authentification on my Flutter application.

Here's the error:

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(400, Failed to generate request token., Please check your APIKey or APISecret., null)

Here's my function :

```
    Future<UserCredential> signInWithTwitter() async {
    final twitterLogin = TwitterLogin(
    apiKey: '...',
    apiSecretKey:'...',
    redirectURI: 'http://localhost:8080/auth/twitter/callback',
    );
    final authResult = await twitterLogin.login();
    final twitterAuthCredential = TwitterAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: authResult.authToken!,
     secret: authResult.authTokenSecret!,
  );
    return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(twitterAuthCredential);
  }
```

And here's how I call it with a button :

```
onPressed: () async {
     await signInWithTwitter();
     Navigator.push(
                 context,
                 MaterialPageRoute(
                 builder: (BuildContext context) => const NextPage()));
},
```

Here's my pubspec.yaml:

```
firebase_core: ^1.12.0
firebase_auth: ^3.3.7
google_sign_in: ^5.2.4
twitter_login: ^4.0.1
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: please check your api key and apisecret key are valid

Comment: @DipakPrajapati I think they are. I just created my Twitter Developper App and copied them into firebase.

Comment: I am facing same issue. have you find any solution ? @ddbbbb

Answer (score 0):

Please use check my code below

```
final twitterLogin = TwitterLogin(
  /// Consumer API keys
  apiKey: 'mX....S5',

  /// Consumer API Secret keys
  apiSecretKey: 'YU....JRjK',

  /// Registered Callback URLs in TwitterApp
  /// Android is a deeplink
  /// iOS is a URLScheme
  redirectURI: '.....',
);
```

If you cannot find it, please regenerate your consumer key [image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after some search and work I found the solution was to add `twittersdk://` to your **Callback URI** in **Twitter Dashboard**
Here is a [reference link](https://github.com/roughike/flutter_twitter_login/issues/8#issuecomment-520294658) to the solution from Github